# if filetype == tex

Tags: vim, latex

I want to run a command in the .vimrc in case a file is a latex file. I think I have something with the syntax, it does not work. Any clue?

```
if &filetype=='tex'
    set spell
endif
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use auto commands to achieve what you want:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex set spell
```

Comment: @user497208 You should use `FileType` event and `:setlocal`: `autocmd FileType tex :setlocal spell`: `FileType` event enables you to do `:set ft=tex` on file with different extension and get spell checking, `:setlocal spell` won't alter the global value of 'spell' option which is default for new buffers.

Comment: In my case actually your advice helped me, I mean to use `FileType` event : `autocmd FileType tex :...'

Comment: Thanks man, made this easy to find and replicate for what I wanted, but let me suggest you throw a `*` in front of the `.txt`

Comment: @ZyX for me, using `FileType` makes my help page also get spell check, so I opted for Loren's answer.

Answer (score 39):

For those who want to check the current filetype and do something while editing, this should work:

```
if (&ft=='c' || &ft=='cpp')
    :!g++ %
endif
```

Comment: That works in a mapping or custom function, but I think the answer was about an action when a Tex file is _opened_.

Comment: I am trying to use something like this:
```let g:tex_flavor='latex'   
if &ft == "tex"            
    set nonu               
endif ```
But it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use `index()`:

```
let fts = ['c', 'cpp']
if index(fts, &filetype) == -1
    " do stuff
endif
```

`index()` searches for the first index of an element in a string, and returns `-1` if not found. This way you can just append more `filetype` values to your list, and not add more conditions for each file type.

Comment: slight issue. index returns the occurance of filetype in list. the statement should be != -1 for it to work. i.e. do stuff if filetype exists in fts

Answer (score 5):

You have to manually detect the filetype first, because vim will detect it automatically only after sourcing your `vimrc`.

Just add this:

```
`filetype detect`
```

before your code.

Answer (score -1):

just to add to above using index. A quick block to check filetypes using ft

***update*** :

```
if index(['tex'], &filetype) != -1
    echom "this is latex filetype!"
endif
```